# .htaccess redirect all calls to forum to specific url

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to add to our .htaccess file so all calls to domain.com/forum go to our new domain.com/site3/forum location.    Note that I do not want to use the actual url, but all calls to that original folder (regardless of url) to go to exactly domain.com/site3/forum.   This would include both secure and insecure version and with or without the www. 
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
Without change for http/https and www

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forum(/|$) /site3/forum [R=301,L]
```

Or all with http and without www:

```
RewriteRule ^forum(/|$) http://example.com/site3/forum [R=301,L]
```

Comment: 500 Error when adding that to the .htaccess file